# How Pass This Error " ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in Python? "

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

**Hi Every One : I want all usernames in CSV file to fit inside an object, but I receive this error :(**

---

```
**Input:**

File = open("Data.csv")
csvreader = csv.reader(File)
header = next(csvreader)
rows = []
for header[2],row in csvreader:
rows.append(row)
print (rows)
File.close()
```

---

```
**Output:**

ValueError         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4704/992967534.py in <module>
      3 header = next(csvreader)
      4 rows = []
----> 5 for header[2],row in csvreader:
      6     rows.append(row)
      7 print (rows)

  ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

**[Image]:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU8Zp.png

Answer (score 0):

You should use `df.iterrows()` it is more convenient regarding csv data frame looping.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [100, 200, 300]})

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['A'], row['B'])
```

Explanation:

When you do not unpack all of the entries in a list, the

> valueerror: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

error occurs.

This error is frequently triggered when an attempt is made to iterate over the elements in a dictionary. To resolve this issue, you should iterate over a dictionary using the items()/iterrows() function.

Nota bene: If I were you, I would paste the code + output straight into stackoverflow rather than using a snapshot.

Cheers.